# Images not loaded from master page in directory

Tags: asp.net, image

I will make a website whit ASP.NET using C# on the background. I have make my master page with the following image:

```
<img src="afbeeldingen/berichten.png" alt="new messages" />
```

Because I have a lot of pages in my site, I have make directories in my solution. My problem is now when I go to a page, it will not load the image. He can't find it. I can edit it to `../images/message.png`, but then can't he find it on the other pages outside the directory.

[image: Images not loaded in directory]

This problem don't happens with the `link`-tag for load my css.

**Important:** all the images are in the master page (yellow on image below). The "child"-page that I will show is in a directory (`localhost:11794/wachtwoord/verloren.aspx` *(in english password/lost)* see blue on image below).

[image]

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559582/css-and-images-on-master-page?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Brendan Hannemann show me a link that where is expaint. The code i must use is:

```
<img src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/afbeeldingen/berichten.png") %>" alt="nieuwe berichten" id="berichten" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `runat="server"` and an ID for the element and you can use `~` to refer to  the root of the solution

```
<img src="~/images/message.png" alt="new messages" runat="server" ID="myImg"/>
```